# Eclipse remote debugging, cannot see properties of object

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm debugging my remote application and I'm confused because I can't see properties of some objects. The sources of this objects are available.

It shows that there are no properties!

Could you please give me advice about that?

By the way, I can see properties of other objects.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Compiler has a function to compile classes with or without debug informations like "line number" and so on.

If the class you are debugging was compiled without debug ifnormations, you can not debug the source code. You will only see the *.class description.

Comment: Do you mean something like com.example.Apple@1dba553 ?

Answer (score 0):

There can be 3 reasons for this.

1. some of your classes are compiled without debug information using `-g:none` option of `javac`. It is relevant for example for classes of JDK.
2. you have different version of classes in your IDE and in application you are trying to debug.
3. Bug in eclipse debugger.

So, here are the solutions.

1. Compile classes with debug information. If these are not your classes, please accept my condolences.
2. make sure you are running same version of classes you have in your IDE.
3. Try to debug again, restart eclipse, refresh, clean your workspace, create new workspaece...